# Would a "mirror driver" collide with the default display driver?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, troubleshooting, vnc

I've just installed UltraVNC, having previously used RealVNC. Both install a "mirror driver", which I assume is a driver that simulates a display to any VNC connections.

Would this mirror driver potentially conflict/clash with a normal video card display driver? I'm asking this generally, or "theoretically".

I'm a bit hesitant about installing it -- first, worried that it will clash with my normal display driver and its overclock (AMD 7950), and second, I'm unaware of the benefits to be gained by a mirror driver, or why they might be desired or beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the benefits part, mirror drivers are a much more efficient way of of capturing the screen. As a basic example if you monitored the cpu % of the server's process while in a connection you would notice it was ~0% when the mirror driver was in use and nothing was happening on the screen, and would rise and fall back to 0% as and when any updates occurred (lots of screen updates like video or "busy" websites would keep the cpu busy, but never excessively so).

If you weren't using the mirror driver and had to fall back to a less efficient method like polling you would notice that the cpu % is never 0% while the server is connected, because the server has to constantly poll the screen for any changes.